# How to handle dynamically returning values given by php with multiple lines?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to realize an indexhandler. Now I can click on a field in HTML and a second window appears. Then, by clicking one of several buttons on the second page, a value gets returned in the field of the first window. This works like this:

```
self.opener.document.getElementById('idOfFieldOnWindow1').value = 'myValue';
```

The value here "`myValue`" gets read out of a database by php. This value can also be a text with more than one lines (it contains at least one or more linebreaks). If I write these values in the code, it gives me a JavaScript Exception:

```
ERROR: unterminated string literal
setValue("Text on which a linebreak follows
```

How can I solve this that I can return the value so it gets shown in the first field including linebreaks?

Comment: You should start by reading the exception

Comment: Please don't write tags in your titles.

Comment: Sorry to say... Are you drunk?

Comment: Is this post really that hard to read?! No, I'm not drunk, but I don't know a better way to describe my problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn your actual line break "\n" into a Javascript text that will produce a line break "\\n".